# File upload from Attachment or URL/link

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-upload, zapier

I want to upload a file using python to our API endpoint [https://developer.revnue.com/reference/upload-file](https://stackoverflow.com) from File attachment/ from url/link. Here's the url of the file where I want to get the file. [https://zapier.com/engine/hydrate/11526390/.eJwdjEtuxCAQBe_SayNhvm7vchKrgWaEkoGRjSdKRnP34GxfvaoXxFY71771nwfDCh8wQalHpxp5KwlWjVY5lDhBPI_e7ufB-z-Y5wE0ygkoxnaOxLWiW5RS450Lf6Wt0v2qlvpsZQQfKY_-5zfttwPWF1wGJEde6eQFysDCoEGxOJtFitZ4w-QWGYbV9hvV8ku9tDqsHBg9WyPMbLUwLJMgbaJgHYMP2WZSDt7vPxINRIs:1pz5DB:uEyKpwm8VAn-xe4pdDvLkVJSCm0/](https://stackoverflow.com).

Here's my code:

```
import requests
import re
import io


def make_download_stream():
file_request = {
'url': "https://zapier.com/engine/hydrate/11526390/.eJwdjEtuxCAQBe_SayNhvm7vchKrgWaEkoGRjSdKRnP34GxfvaoXxFY71771nwfDCh8wQalHpxp5KwlWjVY5lDhBPI_e7ufB-z-Y5wE0ygkoxnaOxLWiW5RS450Lf6Wt0v2qlvpsZQQfKY_-5zfttwPWF1wGJEde6eQFysDCoEGxOJtFitZ4w-QWGYbV9hvV8ku9tDqsHBg9WyPMbLUwLJMgbaJgHYMP2WZSDt7vPxINRIs:1pz5DB:uEyKpwm8VAn-xe4pdDvLkVJSCm0/",
    'method': 'GET',
    'stream': True
     
  url = file_request['url']
  buffer = url.content
  disposition = url.headers.get('content-disposition')
  filename = ''
  filename_regex = r'filename[^;=\n]*=(([""]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)'
  matches = re.findall(filename_regex, disposition)
  if matches and matches[0]:
  filename = matches[0][0].replace("''", "").replace('""', '')
       

 return {
'content-type': url.headers.get('content-type'),
'content': buffer,
'filename': filename
    }
content = make_download_stream()
up_url = 'https://dashboard-api.revnue.com/api/v2/file-upload'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 5547d692ecdbe0794caa571c8607c1cd3e33b38c'}
data = {
    'company': 1
}
files={
 
'filename': open("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Invoice d6a723d7-90be-4949-865f-dc5474ea680b.pdf", 'rb')
}

  formdata = requests.post(up_url,data=data,files=files,headers=headers)
  print(formdata.text)
```